# multi-select tree using javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create a tree with check boxes using a java script object, the data is in below format
data in this format

```
<id, name, parent_id>
```

ex:

```
1   A  -1 
2   B   1
3   C   2
4   d   2 
5   e   2
```

`parent_id` is an "id" and it refers to its parent with that particular "id"

Comment: To create a tree, plant a seed? This makes no sense to us, what is a "tree", how is that data going to be displayed, where are the checkboxes going, why does the parent id matter, and most importantly, what did you try ?

Comment: Sorry if it annoyed u, i'm new to this place... i want to populate a jquery tree with check boxes. http://jsfiddle.net/gurskcga/, here i was passing data from HTML, but i require to pass it using java script object

Comment: @GeekExplorer So you mean you want to create a nested `<ul>` structure based off some JS data, then?

Comment: Okay, and can you post the exact format of the JS object you have the data in? You can use `JSON.stringify(treeConfigVar)` in the devtools console (press F12).

Comment: used console.log, here is the screen shot.. http://i57.tinypic.com/2znpb21.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a crack at this, and here is what I came up with. I commented all the code so you can follow the logic. Hopefully this helps you learn.

```js
var data = [{
  label: "3138 | Root Organization | -1",
  selected: true,
  value: "3138"
}, {
  label: "3140 | Company X | 3138",
  selected: false,
  value: "3140"
}, {
  label: "3148 | Corporate | 3140",
  selected: false,
  value: "3148"
}];

var nodes = {},
  tree = [];

// construct the map of nodes and the tree structure
// by looping over the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  // split the label based on <spaces>|<spaces> and
  // create a node object with the relevant properties
  var parts = d.label.split(/\s+\|\s+/),
    node = {
      id: parts[0],
      name: parts[1],
      parentId: parts[2],
      children: []
    },
    parentNode;
  // if there is no parent, this must be a top level
  // node, so add it to our tree array.
  if (node.parentId === "-1") {
    tree.push(node);
  } else {
    // otherwise, the parent must be an existing node
    // so just add this node to its children
    parentNode = nodes[node.parentId];
    if (parentNode) {
      parentNode.children.push(node);
    }
  }
  // store this node in the map by id so we can
  // look it up easily
  nodes[node.id] = node;
});

// the function that recursively draws the tree
// params: 
//    element: (string|DOMElement|jQuery) the element to
//    append the tree to
//    tree: (node[]) the array of nodes to draw 
//           at the current level
function drawTree(element, tree) {
  var $ul = $('<ul>');
  tree.forEach(function(node) {
    var $li = $('<li>');
    $li.text(node.name);
    // if this node has children, draw them inside
    // the current <li>
    if (node.children.length !== 0) {
      drawTree($li, node.children);
    }
    $ul.append($li);
  });
  $ul.appendTo(element);
}

// invoke the function with the tree data
drawTree('#out', tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```